# How to get the file URL from Google drive in PHP?

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

I tried to use [the Google Drive API quickstart.php](https://github.com/googleworkspace/php-samples/blob/main/drive/quickstart/quickstart.php) and changed part of it to list the file URL. However it didn't work. Can anyone help me?

Here is my code, the last part of the code is to print name, id, and URL of the files.

```php
<?php
/**
 * Copyright 2018 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
// [START drive_quickstart]
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
    throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

use Google\Client;
use Google\Service\Drive;

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google\Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Drive API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE,"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly");
    $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://127.0.0.1/home/ubuntu/intern/quickstart.php');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('consent');
    $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    try{


        if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
            if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
                $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
            } else {
                // Request authorization from the user.
                $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
                printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
                print 'Enter verification code: ';
                $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

                // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
                $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
                $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

                // Check to see if there was an error.
                if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                    throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
                }
            }
            // Save the token to a file.
            if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
                mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
            }
            file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        // TODO(developer) - handle error appropriately
        echo 'Some error occured: '.$e->getMessage();
    }
    return $client;
}


// Get the API client and construct the drive object.
$client = getClient();
$drive = new Google\Service\Drive($client);

// Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files.
$optParams = array(
    'pageSize' => 10,
    'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name, webContentLink)'
);
$results = $drive->files->listFiles($optParams);

if (count($results->getFiles()) == 0) {
    print "No files found.\n";
} else {
    print "Files:\n";
    foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
        printf("%s (%s)", $file->getName(), $file->getId());
        $webContentLink = $file->getWebContentLink();
        if (!empty($webContentLink)) {
            printf("Web Content Link: %s\n", $webContentLink);
        }
        else{
            echo"can't generate URL \n";
        }
    }
}
// [END drive_quickstart]
```

I expect there will exist the URL in my terminal, but it didn't.

[image]

Comment: What file URL are you expecting exactly

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo, thank you for answering me. I wanted to list the shared link of the file which can open the file, but it didn't return the link. I can't find the problem.

Comment: The API cannot return a share Link.   We content link would be a link for the owner of the file to open a Google drive file type in the web app.   And only a file.get will return that not a file.list

Comment: oh done! Thank you! But may I ask, how do you know which method to use to find those attributes we want? Like if I want to download or upload the file to drive? I just leant php a few days so I don't know much.

Comment: I have been working with these apis for ten years I know the documentation

Answer (score 1):

#### Modification points:

- In the current stage, the values of `webContentLink` return only when the mimeType is not a Google Docs file (Document, Spreadsheet, Slide, and so on) and folder. I guessed that from the length of your showing file ID, the reason for `can't generate URL` might be due to this.
- If you want to show the view link, how about using `webViewLink` instead of `webContentLink`?
- Or, if you want to use `webContentLink`, how about checking the mimeType of the file?

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, `webViewLink` is used instead of `webContentLink`.

```php
$client = getClient();
$drive = new Google\Service\Drive($client);

// Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files.
$optParams = array(
    'pageSize' => 10,
    'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name, webViewLink)'
);
$results = $drive->files->listFiles($optParams);

if (count($results->getFiles()) == 0) {
    print "No files found.\n";
} else {
    print "Files:\n";
    foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
        printf("%s (%s)", $file->getName(), $file->getId());
        $webViewLink = $file->getWebViewLink();
        printf("Web View Link: %s\n", $webViewLink);
    }
}
```

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, `webContentLink` is used by checking the mimeType. If the mimeType is Google Docs file, `webViewLink` is used.

```php
$client = getClient();
$drive = new Google\Service\Drive($client);

// Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files.
$optParams = array(
    'pageSize' => 10,
    'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name, webContentLink, mimeType, webViewLink)'
);
$results = $drive->files->listFiles($optParams);

if (count($results->getFiles()) == 0) {
    print "No files found.\n";
} else {
    print "Files:\n";
    foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
        printf("%s (%s)", $file->getName(), $file->getId());
        if (false === strpos($file->getMimeType(), 'application/vnd.google-apps')) {
            $webContentLink = $file->getWebContentLink();
            printf("Web Content Link: %s\n", $webContentLink);
        } else {
            $webViewLink = $file->getWebViewLink();
            printf("Web View Link: %s\n", $webViewLink);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Note:

- In the above scripts, if you want to use the shared link, please modify this script as follows.

  - From

    ```php
    printf("Web View Link: %s\n", $webViewLink);
    ```
  - To

    ```php
    printf("Web View Link: %s\n", str_replace('drivesdk', 'sharing', $webViewLink));
    ```
- If you want to retrieve the URLs for exporting the files, when the mimeType is Google Docs file, how about using `exportLinks`?

#### Reference:

- [Method: files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/list)